# Adding choices using caml query

Tags: sharepoint-2013, caml

I am writing a caml query to add column in sharepoint. The field is 'choice' type.

I have written the query like,
choice1
choice2
/>

This is throwing an error that name can't start with '<' character.
Can anyone please help to tell how I can add choices for a field using caml query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caml Query is used to filter field value not adding column, if you want to add choices into a choice type field, you could add the AddFieldAsXml like this which will involve choices, write all the needed choices in the xml:

```
        string siteUrl = "http://sp/sites/dev";
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Administrator", "Access1", "Contoso");
        List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("DemoList1");
        Field catField = oList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(@"
            <Field Type='Choice' DisplayName='Category' Format='Dropdown'>
                <Default>IT</Default>
                <CHOICES>
                  <CHOICE>IT</CHOICE>
                  <CHOICE>Sales</CHOICE>
                </CHOICES>
        </Field>", true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
        oList.Update();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

[image]